# I'm building three pages using react, each of them has its own css file and only one css file is working for everyone of them

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on these three pages:
App.js has two buttons, when you click on the first button it takes you to page "/quotes", and when you click on the second button it takes you to page "/recommendations". The htmls of all three are working BUT whenever i go to "/quotes" or "/recommendations" the App.js html content AND css content continues to appear (in a very weird and broken way, it looks very bad).
Heres an example: [image]

this is my code:
App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import QuotePage from './QuotePage.js'
import RecommendationPage from './RecommendationPage.js'

function App() {

  return (
     <div className="all-page"> 
     <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/quotes" element={<QuotePage/>}/>
            <Route path="/recommendations" element={<RecommendationPage/>}/>
        </Routes>
      
    </Router>
             <main className="central-div">
                <h2>Taylor's Songs</h2>
                
                <a href="/quotes" className="quote-bttn">
                  FIND ME A QUOTE
                </a>
                <a href="/recommendations" className="recommend-bttn">
                    GET ME A RECOMMENDATION
                </a>
             </main>
        </div>
  );
  
    
}
export default App;
```

QuotePage.js:

```
import './QuotePage.css';

function QuotePage() {
  return (
     <h1>testing</h1>
  );
 
}

export default QuotePage;
```

QuotePage.css (I only made this for testing):

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

RecommendationPage.js:

```
import './RecommendationPage.css';
function RecommendationPage() {
  return (
    <div className="test">
         <h1>this should be the recommendation page!</h1>
    </div>
    
  );
  
 
}

export default RecommendationPage;
```

RecommendationPage.css:

```
*{
    background: rgba(191, 240, 243, 0.94);
}
.test{
    background-color: rgb(234, 83, 83);
    height: 30px;
}
```

If there's anything missing here, I'm sorry and would really appreciate if you took a quick look to check if it's here: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/my-taylor-swift-api/tree/master/front

Thank you SO much for anyone who tries to help me!!! <3

Comment: Hi Vitoriac, I'm not sure what the CSS-related title has to do with your actual question but so you know, CSS will cascade through your React pages, which means you can create a single CSS file that, with some planning, can work well for the entire React site. For routing, I agree with Joseph. I use React-Router's Outlet component and context attribute to basically replace content in-place within a single container. If you haven't done so already, do React's tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html and read "Thinking in React" at https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're falling for a trap commonly experienced with new people to react: it's not structured like HTML.

While this isn't strictly true, it's helpful to start off as thinking that react has only one screen/page: app.js. You pull other content into this page using components. This is called managing state.

Because you have all of that code in app.js, it will continue to appear. What you need to do is create a separate file (say, "home.js") and put that code in there.

You then need to do the routing with a tool like react-router-dom so that you can change the content on the screen.

Once you've done that, you'll have begin to see how react works.

So:

1. Move all of that content into a new file called home.js
2. install react-router-dom with npm
3. create a new file called navbar.js and create a navigation bar for your site with it
4. when done, only call navbar.js as a component in app.js
5. add your pages as routes

You'll need to read up on react-router-dom but it's pretty straightforward